# Codewars and Mathematica

Tags: programming, core-language, coding-style

I looked up the Wolfram Language on [Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/) as the site is great to improve coding.
WL is not among the listed languages (I checked the beta versions as well). I assume this is because the language is not freely available for use. In any case, the question is: what are the best sites to sharpen your WL-coding? Are there online series of exercise one can do to improve? Codewars is great I gather since after solving the problem, shorter code is offered for the same problem. It is easier to learn the advantages of certain ways of coding after having produced a solution for the problem. I tend to learn in bouts, reading books and practicing concepts I learned, alternating with necessity-driven solutions to research problems with the help of Mathematica. I enjoy problem solving in general, so having a site that provides short challenges and alternative solutions would be a great help. I am aware of Project Euclid, which is fun, but I hope to find something closer in spirit to Codewars. Any suggestions?

Comment: Answer questions on this site and compare your answer with the other answers. I learned Mathematica answering questions on MathGroup until it disappeared, then switched to MSE.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice/259#259

Comment: I am sure it has been mentioned in the links but you can always join the [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) SE and solve the challenging questions to sharpen your skills.

Comment: "I am aware of Project Euclid" Do you mean Project Euler? Or there's also a Project Euclid?

Comment: @BobHanlon sure. Often the answer is accepted when I take a look. I assume it is not allowed to post after that point.

Comment: Thanks @Syed I was not aware of codegolf

Comment: The only thing that would preclude an answer would be if the question were closed. You can always answer after an answer is accepted; particularly if you can offer something that demonstrates a novel approach.

Comment: @Michel You can absolutely post an answer at any point. You can find many examples of answers posted after another that was accepted on this site, even years afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoB and Bob Hanlon that's great!